# In Travis-CI, how can I have a different matrix for pull requests?

Tags: travis-ci

Is there a proper way to create a build matrix specific for Pull Requests?

The idea is:

- In normal builds, I want to test a few things only (code style/standards, some unit tests, some general validation). Mostly one item only in the build matrix.
- In pull requests, I want to run the tests with several different environments, including different databases and versions. This is what I currently have but it demands a lot from travis (and it is slow).

I know I can achieve that in the script by checking TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST and skipping the tests, but that will misleadingly show some environments as "passed" when they were actually not tested.

Thank you for any help / guidance,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting wish!

This is not possible at the moment. You might want to chime in on https://github.com/travis-ci/beta-features/issues/11 to bring it to the attention of the relevant people.

Comment: Thanks, I added a comment on that tracker, there are many other ideas there that could achieve similar feature.

Thank you!